# can't call qwinsta with pythonw

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system

I'm trying to build an application which uses the **wx** module for the graphical part. My operating system is windows 10 and the python version is 2.7.

This application should check if someone is remote connected to the computer and change the color of a button if so. 
To check if someone is connected to the computer, i parse the output of the **qwinsta** call.

> I have to specify this: to run this application i use **pythonw**.

The code block is the following:

```
def isLocked():
    process =subprocess.Popen('qwinsta',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    output,error = process.communicate()
    print output
    output2 = output[0:len(output)]

    output2= output2.split('\n')
```

The problem is that, the subprocess call i made returns an error:

> 'qwinsta' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"""

I think i found the problem but i don't know how to solve it:

This subprocess call works fine if i would call it with **python**. If i use **pythonw** it fails. To me it seems like **pythonw** uses the *syswow64/cmd.exe*, and **python** uses the *system32/cmd.exe*.

I checked the os.environ variable on both **python** and **pythonw** and the *COMSPEC* variable is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a work around the problem. 
I still think the problem was that the **pythonw** uses the *windows/syswow64/cmd.exe* .
This **cmd** seems to be unable to execute the **qwinsta.exe** executable which is found in the *Syste32* folder.

*But this **qwista.exe** is also found in the *windows/WinSxS* folder, where the syswow64/cmd.exe has access and is able to run the executable.

The work around was that, i gave to the subprocess Popen the path to the *windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-t..commandlinetoolsmqq_31bf3856ad364e35...* **qwinsta.exe**

```
process =subprocess.Popen('',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False,executable='C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64...\qwinsta.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the workaround works great, here is some code more complete in case the status is needed for a remote PC

```
import subprocess

#This could be also the ip
remote_desktop_name = MY_PC_NAME

#Searh the path where qwinsta is located for 64 bits cmd
#It may start as C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-t ...
qwinsta_path = r'THE_PATH_WHERE_QWINSTA_IS_FOR_64BITS_CMD'

process = subprocess.Popen(['qwinsta', remote_desktop_name],
                    env = os.environ,        
                    shell=True, 
                    cwd = qwinsta_path,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

#Wait for the remote connection to respond
process.wait()
#Get error and output
out, err = process.communicate()


print(out)
print(err)
```